# Rest camel passing objects between endpoints

Tags: spring, apache-camel, message-queue

**Overview**.
My camel setup calls two service methods.  the response of the first one is passed into the second one and then output the final response as json webpage.  Fairly simple nothing too complicated.

**Further breakdown to give some more context.**
Method_1.  Takes in scanId.  This works ok.  It produces an object called ScheduledScan .class
Method_2.  Takes in object previous instance of ScheduledScan .class and returns a  list of ConvertedScans  scans.  Then would like to display said list

Description of the code

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {

    restConfiguration().bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json);

    rest("/publish")
       .get("/scheduled-scan/{scanId}")
       .to("bean:SentinelImportService?method=getScheduledScan").outType(ScheduledScan .class)
       .to("bean:SentinelImportService?method=convertScheduledScan");
}
```

The methods that are called look like the following

```
ScheduledScan  getScheduledScan(@Header("scanId") long scanId);
List<ConvertedScans >  convertScheduledScan(@Body ScheduledScan  scheduledScans);
```

It is returning the the following error

No body available of type: path. .ScheduledScan  but has value:
of type: java.lang.String on: HttpMessage@0x63c2fd04. Caused by: No type converter available

The following runs without the error, i.e. without method 2.  So I think im almost there.

```
rest("/publish")
.get("/scheduled-scan/{scanId}")
.to("bean:SentinelImportService?method=getScheduledScan");
```

Now from reading the error it looks like im passing in a HttpMessage not the java object?   I'm a bit confused about what to do next?  Any advice much appreciated.

I have found some similar questions to this message.  However I am looking to pass the java object directly into the service method.

[camel-rest-bean-chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32565267/camel-rest-bean-chaining)

[how-to-share-an-object-between-methods-on-different-camel-routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21681773/how-to-share-an-object-between-methods-on-different-camel-routes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should setup the `outType` as the last output, eg what the REST response is, that is a List/Array and not a single pojo. So use `.outTypeList(ConvertedScans.class)` instead.